# Why nginx sub_filter does not work with proxy_pass?

Tags: javascript, nginx, iframe

### Goal

I want to bypass **same origin policy** on an `iframe` via reverse proxy to have some javascript control over the website inside the `iframe`.

### Problem 1

`src` of the iframe is set to `https://example1.com/iframe-app`. But this still rises same origin policy violation in the browser. So browser still sees the page inside the iframe as it does not originate from `https://example1.com/` and this seems okay since if the underlying page has same origin then its ajax requests will not work.

### Problem 2

So I tried using nginx `sub_filter` directive to inject my javascript into response html. Nothing is added to the response though. Maybe this is because the response is encrypted due to https protocol?

### Question

Why `sub_filter` does not work and how to make it to work?

### nginx Config

```
server {
    
            root /var/www/example1.com/html;
            index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
            server_name example1.com www.example1.com;
    
    
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
            }
    
            location /iframe-app {
                    rewrite ^/iframe-app(.*) /$1 break;

                    proxy_pass http://example2.com;
                    
                    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
                    
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    
                    sub_filter '</head>' '<script>...code</script></head>';
                    sub_filter_once on;
                    sub_filter_types text/html;
    
            }
    
    
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
    
    server {
        if ($host = www.example1.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
        if ($host = example1.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;
    
            server_name example1.com www.example1.com;
            return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

Comment: You have a typo here: sub_filter_once on`; Please fix it in your question if you don't have it in your real config. Also indicate if you already tried any solution from a duplicate question, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893211/http-sub-module-sub-filter-of-nginx-and-reverse-proxy-not-working)